# Maven: Deploying a jar/war with built in pom.xml file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I don't have a Maven project. What I have is a jar with the `pom.xml` embedded in the file. When I deploy this via the Artifactory GUI, Artifactory finds the pom and deploys it with the jar. It even recognizes the groupId, artifactId, and version.

When I try using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` it fails. If I extract the pom, and run `mvn deploy:deploy-file` with the `-DpomFile=pom.xml`, it works. Is there a way of deploying this jar with the embedded pom via the Maven command line? Or, do I need to extract the pom.xml first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard of the possibility to specify the pom file from archive. I think it is unlikely to be an option, because Maven itself is just a light-weight program, which runs with plugins; and it needs some configurations to run with; and all references to plugins to be used are in those files.

Consider writing an Ant script that will extract the file, run `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=pom.xml` and then delete the file.

The solution looks not very nice, I know, but it should help.

Comment: You're probably right. What I originally was doing is creating the `pom.xml` and saving it in Jenkins with the jar. However, I was deploying a jar w/ an embedded pom.xml in Artifactory, and Artifactory found it and used it. I thought maybe this was a standard Maven thing, but no go. I'll revert back to my old method, and use `deploy:deploy-file` as before.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Artifactory feature and not standard Maven behaviour.

Keep in mind that, for example, if you use dependency:unpack-dependencies or the assembly plugin to create some sort of über jar there would be multiple pom.xml files within the jar under the /META-INF/ path so it would be very difficult to select which pom was the true pom.